# Detect whether the intent of a user is to tap or to scroll up/down the page on tactile device

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ios, touch

If a user taps (`touchstart`) outside a popup-div, I want to hide the popup.

But if the user's intent is to scroll/swipe (`touchmove`), I don't want to hide the popup.

How could the code look like to detect and respond to those two actions (with or without jQuery)?

Comment: try detecting long touch for swipe and short touch for touch

Comment: Could you give an example what that could look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a basic example of how you could do this:
http://jsfiddle.net/4CrES/2/

The logic behind it involves detecting the initial touch time and saving it to a var

```
touchTime = new Date();
```

In the touchend handler subtract this time from the current time to get the difference:

```
var diff = new Date() - touchTime;
```

Use an if statement to decide whether the touch duration was short enough to consider it a tap, or long enough to consider it a drag.

```
if (diff < 100){
    //It's a tap
}
else {
    //Not a quick tap
}
```

You could write a more robust implementation by doing a similar difference of the initial touch y position to the final touch y position in the handlers. Another option is to compare the scrollTop of the scrolling area to see if it has been scrolled.

Comment: updated the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4CrES/3/ to work the same on the browser as well. So mousedown (touchstart in touch device) and mouseup (touchend in touch device) are added as events so that same effect is observed in browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Since click events do not bubble up the DOM on mobile Safari while touch events and custom events do, I recently wrote some code to detect a quick-tap.

It's a quick-tap when

- The touch event starts and ends without any movement along the screen
- No scrolling occurrs
- It all happens in less than 200ms.

If the touch is determined to be a 'quickTap', the TouchManager causes the touched element in the DOM to emit a custom "quickTap" event which then bubbles up the DOM to any other elements that happen to be listening for it. This code defines and creates the touch manager and it will be ready to go immediately

Drawbacks:

- Uses jQuery
- Only designed with one finger in mind.
- also borrowed some code from modernizr. (You can omit that bit if you already include Modernizr.)

Maybe this is overkill, but it's part of a larger codebase I'm working on.

```
/** 
 * Click events do not bubble up the DOM on mobile Safari unless the click happens on a link or form input, but other events do bubble up.
 * The quick-tap detects the touch-screen equivalent of a click and triggers a custom event on the target of the tap which will bubble up the DOM.
 * A touch is considered a click if there is a touch and release without any movement along the screen or any scrolling.
 */

var qt = (function ($) {
    /**
     * Modernizr 3.0.0pre (Custom Build) | MIT 
     * Modernizr's touchevent test
     */
    var touchSupport = (function() {
            var bool,
                prefixes = ' -webkit- -moz- -o- -ms- '.split(' ')
            if(('ontouchstart' in window) || window.DocumentTouch && document instanceof DocumentTouch) {
                bool = true;
            } else {
                var query = ['@media (',prefixes.join('touch-enabled),('),'heartz',')','{#modernizr{top:9px;position:absolute}}'].join('');
                testStyles(query, function( node ) {
                    bool = node.offsetTop === 9;
                });
            }
            return bool;
        }()),
        MobileTapEvent = 'tapEvent';

    if(touchSupport) {
        /* Create a new qt (constructor)*/
        var startTime = null,
            startTouch = null,
            isActive = false,
            scrolled = false;

        /* Constructor */
        function qt() {
            var _qt = this,
                context = $(document);
            context.on("touchstart", function (evt) {
                startTime = evt.timeStamp;
                startTouch = evt.originalEvent.touches.item(0);
                isActive = true;
                scrolled = false;
            })
            context.on("touchend", function (evt) {
                window.ct = evt.originalEvent['changedTouches'];
                // Get the distance between the initial touch and the point where the touch stopped.
                var duration = evt.timeStamp - startTime,
                    movement = _qt.getMovement(startTouch, evt.originalEvent['changedTouches'].item(0)), 
                    isTap = !scrolled && movement < 5 && duration < 200;
                if (isTap) {
                    $(evt.target).trigger('quickTap', evt);
                }
            })
            context.on('scroll mousemove touchmove', function (evt) {
                if ((evt.type === "scroll" || evt.type === 'mousemove' || evt.type === 'touchmove') && isActive && !scrolled) {
                    scrolled = true;
                }
            });
        }

        /* Calculate the movement during the touch event(s)*/
        qt.prototype.getMovement = function (s, e) {
            if(!s || !e) return 0;
            var dx = e.screenX - s.screenX, 
                dy = e.screenY - s.screenY;
            return Math.sqrt((dx * dx) + (dy * dy));
        };
        return new qt();
    }
}(jQuery));
```

To use the code you would add it to your page then just listen for the quickTap event.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="quick-tap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('quickTap', function(evt, originalEvent) {
        console.log('tap event detected on: ', evt.target.nodeName, 'tag');
    });
</script>
```

**evt** is the quickTap event.

**evt.target** is the tapped DOM element (not the jQuery object).

**originalEvent** is the touchend event where qt determines whether it was a tap or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the popup-div on `touchend` event.
In `touchstart` event you remember window.scrollY.
In `touchend` event, if `scrollY` positions differ the user has scrolled.